# Insallation failed on devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")

Tags: r, r-markdown

I use R 3.4.3, And I need to install devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown"). But the following installation error comes up.

```
Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/rmarkdown@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/rmarkdown/zipball/master
Installation failed: zip file 'C:\Users\Buster\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWyl4FP\file3bc6c571eec.zip' cannot be opened
Warning messages:
1: GitHub repo contains submodules, may not function as expected! 
2: In utils::unzip(src, exdir = target) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

How can I install this?

Comment: It still does not work

Answer (score 0):

this has been resolved. I used devtools::install_url("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rmarkdown_1.9.tar.gz")

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [README](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/README.md) for rmarkdown:

> If you are working within RStudio then you can simply install the
>   current release of RStudio (both the rmarkdown package and pandoc are
>   included).
>
> If you want to use the rmarkdown package outside of RStudio then you
>   can install the package from CRAN as follows:

```
install.packages("rmarkdown")
```

This is a much more concise way of doing:

```
devtools::install_url("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rmarkdown_1.9.tar.gz")
```